how do i return the json object of my ajax GET request to an API in Asp.net MVC
Ok hi. I'm having a lot of problems with a project im building. I want to use Ajax to make a request to the Google.Books api so I can make book searches from my website. Its a Asp.net MVC project. I'm using Ajax on one of the pages.
The documentation says just send a GET request to the url. I wrote the ajax request and I seem to get an 200 ok response but im not getting the json object.
Also i want to put the info from the json response to show the title of the book and the author. Possibly a dropdown in html or a select div in html.
$(document).ready(function () {

$('getBookList').submit(function () {
    var key = "AIzaSyAAD3qgVCx8MeoD6aD-CzTasKijPE-Ny3Y";

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=search+terms&" + key,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data: { volumeInfo: title, volumeInfo: authors },
        success: function (data) {

            $('#volumeInfo:title').dropdown("show")(data)
            $('#volumeInfo:authors').dropdown("show")(data)
            $('#q').dropdown("show")(data)

                .fail(function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                    alert("Sorry, there was a problem!");
                    console.log("Error: " + errorThrown);
                    console.log("Status: " + status);
                    console.dir(xhr);

                });

        }
    });
});

});

What happens if you log data in your success() callback? Does your network tab show a response?

The call to the API is working absolutely fine. The issue is because there's a lot of syntax issues in your success handler. First, I don't know what dropdown library you're using, but having a function that returns a function in order to call another function is extremely unlikely to be the correct pattern. Check the dropdown() documentation. Also the .fail() call should not be hanging in the middle of your code. I assume this is supposed to be attached to the $.ajax() call?

The dropdown is an input id from bootstrap.  You would enter the search term and the get request would use the q parameter to search for the book json.  But what i have found on google is that the best way is to use a select  div and use css to change it.

Firstly, you are sending a Get request, so that I can test in my side with your URL and I can get the JSON result. Then your codes... we can see a form submit and within the submit it's a ajax query, and you set the data type as jsonp.. It's really complex. By the way, $('getBookList') is pointing to which element? form id or name or <getBookList></getBookList>? Would you like to do a searching when the page is loading and without any searching keywords?

By the way, your query url seems incorrect. See this sample. And your desired query shall be https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=intitle:{searching title}+inauthor:{searching author name}&{yourkey}

ok thank you!! I'll check.

Firstly, let's refer to the Google.Books API, we could see that if we want to search for author and title of a book, we have intitle and inauthor property. And the query request shall be a GET request like below which title contains "Flowers" and author name contains "Daniel".
https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=intitle:Flowers+inauthor:Daniel&{key}

Since OP wants to do a query when the page is loading and have a search button for searching manually. I have a sampe like below.
<div>
    <span>
        <laber>title</laber>
        <input type="text" id="title" />
    </span>
    <span>
        <laber>authors</laber>
        <input type="text" id="authors" />
    </span>
    <button id="getBookList">search</button>
</div>
    
<div>
    <label>result for authors</label>
    <select id="mySelect">
        <option value="">Select an option</option>
    </select>
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#getBookList').click();
});

$('#getBookList').click(function () {
    var key = "your key";
    var title = $('#title').val();
    var authors = $('#authors').val();
    var queryString = "q=intitle:" + title + "+inauthor:" + authors;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?" + queryString +"&" + key,
        success: function (data) {
            console.info(data);
            var select = $('#mySelect');
            select.empty();
            $.each(data.items, function (index, item) {
                var temp = item.volumeInfo.authors.join(', ');
                select.append($('<option>', {
                    value: item.id,  // seems to be the book id
                    text: temp
                }));
            });
        }
    });
});



It's just a demo, and I found that the volumeInfo property might not contain authors property so that we have to check null value too.

Thank you! I'll check my code and make the corrections.
